# How to go to Grid view directly when SQL is executed in TOAD?

Tags: toad

I have this issue which is really annoying.

When I run a query in TOAD (version 11.5.1.2), it shows the result in **Script Output** tab, and then within its child **Output** tab.

The **Output** tab shows unformatted data, like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_AWARD_ID   AWARD_ID EMPLOYEE_ID INVESTED_AMT_ANNUAL INVESTED_AMT_CLIFF
----------------- ---------- ----------- ------------------- ------------------
MATCHING_AMT_ANNUAL MATCHING_AMT_CLIFF INVESTED_SHARES_ANNUAL
------------------- ------------------ ----------------------
INVESTED_SHARES_CLIFF MATCHING_SHARES_ANNUAL MATCHING_SHARES_CLIFF
--------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------
MATCHING_SHARES_FRAC_AMT INVESTED_SHARES_FRAC_AMT TOTAL_INVESTED_DIVIDEND_SHARES
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------------
TOTAL_MATCHING_DIVIDEND_SHARES TSR_SHARES EPS_SHARES TSR_AMOUNT EPS_AMOUNT
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
            16813        103         450                   0                  0
                  0                  0                    182
                    0                    182                     0
                       0                        0                              0
                             0          0          0          0          0

1 row selected.
```

I want to make TOAD open the **Script Output** -> **Grid 1** tab by default, whenever I run a query, because this tabl shows the result in the form of a grid ... Or it should open **Data Grid** tab instead, which also shows the result in a data grid.

Anyone know how to do this ?

Currently I have to manually switch to the **Grid 1** or **Data Grid** tab manually, everytime I run a query, and this very annoying ! :(

Comment: We might need a example SQL query. Normally you get a grid view by default unless you actually receive text output from the query.

Comment: Also, which version of Toad are you using: TOAD for oracle?, Toad for SQL server? etc.

Answer (score 7):

Found it!
Instead of hitting F5 to execute your SQL statement, instead press the "green arrow head" icon to execute the statement.

I have the default layout and this button is on the left hand side just above the tab containing my SQL query.

Unfortunately I do not have sufficient privileges to upload images, so can't send a screenshot.

Comment: This is the icon with the "Execute Statement" tooltip -- on my version of Toad (for Oracle) it's mapped to F9 by default. So hitting F9 on a query ought to give you a data grid instead of unformatted text.

Answer (score 3):

F5 is Execute as Statement - Raw Output
F9 is Execute as Script - Grid Output (Alternate: CTRL-ENTER)

When running as a Statement and switching to grid, you'll be in the Script Output tab which has actions available (copy/select all, etc). When running as a Script you have a Data Grid view you'll have only export action. You can switch views at either output.

You can remap the function keys if you are accustomed to F5.

EDIT: The version I based my response on is for Toad for Oracle 11.6

Answer (score 1):

The button that sends output directly to the grid is located on the Execute toolbar and looks like this:

[image]

You can set it to execute via F5 by doing the following:

- Choose View->ToadOptions
- Left side scroll and under Toolbars/Menus choose Shortcuts
- Right side click on 'Execute Statement' (F9 is shown as shortcut on mine)
- Hit F5
- Click on 'Execute as Script' (F5 is still shown as shortcut here)
- Hit F9

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl + Enter` to execute the sql command and get the Data Grid view.